# The logo disappear in mobile environment

Tags: css, joomla

I am new to this website so there might be similar question.

I have created the website with Joomla using Bootstrap.

http://theeruditepen.com/

I needed to update the website and after I updated, everytime the top logo (the top of the page and image (theEruditePen_Logo1.png) disappear in the mobile environment.

It used to show before, but some update change made the logo disappear and I do not  find out how to fix it...I really want to show this logo even the mobile environment on top of menu.

I would really appreciate any tips and help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <img 
    src="/templates/theeruditepen/images/theEruditePen_Logo1.png" 
    class="visible-tablet visible-desktop img-responsive"
    >
```

Remove `visible-tablet visible-desktop` class from the image tag.

The above classes will show the image only on tablets and desktops, and will hide it on mobile devices.
If u want to show the image on all devices, then remove the classes.

Or you can add `.visible-phone` to make it visible on phones

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue in the past.. the solution for me it was the following:

First I checked the type of module in which my element was placed (custom module, articles module, category module, etc).

After that, I checked the especific module option configuration (image attached as an example) and set the mobile option to on. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv4OB.png)

Hope it helps.